# Not getting exact line number because of Spring CGLIB

Tags: spring-boot, exception, aspectj, spring-aop, stack-trace

I am working on a Spring Boot application. I have defined an exception aspect, in order to customize and send meaningful error codes in the API response for service classes something like the below:

```java
@Aspect
@Order(0)
public class TcInternalExceptionAspect {

  private static final String INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = "Internal Server Error";
  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcInternalExceptionAspect.class); 

  @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
  public void applicationServicePointcut() { }    

  @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "applicationServicePointcut()", throwing = "e")
  public void translate(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
    String resourceId = getResourceId();
    if (e instanceof JDBCException) {
     String message = (StringUtils.isBlank(e.getMessage()) ?
      e.getClass() : e.getMessage());
     log.error(message);
     throw new BadServerStateException("Internal Server Error", resourceId,
      DATABASE_ERROR_CODE);
   } else {
     String message = (StringUtils.isBlank(e.getMessage()) ?
      e.getClass() : e.getMessage());
     log.error(message);
     throw new BadServerStateException("Internal Server Error", resourceId,
      INTERNAL_ERROR_CODE);
  }
 }
```

`BadServerStateException` looks like the below:

```java
import org.zalando.problem.AbstractThrowableProblem;

public class BadServerStateException extends AbstractThrowableProblem {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final String entityName;
  private final String errorKey;
  private final String errorType;

  public BadServerStateException(String defaultMessage, String entityName, String errorKey) {
    this(defaultMessage, entityName, Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, errorKey,
        ErrorTypes.SYSTEM_ERROR.name());
  }

  public BadServerStateException(String defaultMessage, String entityName, String errorKey,
                                 String errorType) {
    this(defaultMessage, entityName, Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, errorKey, errorType);
  }

  public BadServerStateException(String defaultMessage,  String message, String entityName,
                             StatusType statusType, String errorKey, String errorType) {


 super(null, defaultMessage, statusType, null, null, null,
        getAlertParameters(message));
    this.entityName = entityName;
    this.errorKey = errorKey;
    this.errorType = errorType;
  }

  public BadServerStateException(String defaultMessage, String entityName, StatusType statusType,
                                 String errorKey, String errorType) {
    super(null, defaultMessage, statusType, null, null, null,
        getAlertParameters(defaultMessage));
    this.entityName = entityName;
    this.errorKey = errorKey;
    this.errorType = errorType;
  }

  private static Map<String, Object> getAlertParameters(String defaultMessage) {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(defaultMessage)) {
      parameters.put(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_PARAMETER_NAME, defaultMessage);
    }
    return parameters;
  }

  public String getEntityName() {
    return entityName;
  }

  public String getErrorKey() {
    return errorKey;
  }

  public String getErrorType() {
    return errorType;
  }
```

}

In case of any API error, I am getting an error log something like the below:

```
com.mycom.tc.exception.external.BadServerStateException: Internal Server Error
    at com.mycom.tc.exception.TcInternalExceptionAspect.translate(TcInternalExceptionAspect.java:73)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:617)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.mycom.tm.service.impl.MyServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b4c3687b.myFunction(<generated>)
    at com.mycom.tm.web.rest.MyResource.createDocument(MyResource.java:46)
    at com.mycom.tm.web.rest.MyResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$43df49a4.invoke(<generated>)
```

As you can see in the above log snipper, I am not getting the exact line of error in `myFunction`, not able to understand how to get this.

Could someone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your reproducer? Please learn how to ask questions by means of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It looks as if you are throwing an exception from `TcInternalExceptionAspect.translate`. Why? The `@AfterThrowing` advice is meant to intercept an exception which was thrown already by the intercepted method, not to throw another one instead. What are you trying to do, and why are you hiding the very code that causes your problem behind "..."? Does that make any sense? Could you answer a question like this?

Comment: @kriegaex I added more details for the aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you are seeing is not due to CGLIB, it is due to the way you handle exceptions. It is not even related to Spring AOP or Spring as such, really.

Does your `BadServerStateException` not have a constructor with a `Throwable cause` like this?

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968;

public class BadServerStateException extends RuntimeException {
  public BadServerStateException(String internalServerError, String resourceId, Object p2) {
    this(internalServerError, resourceId, p2, null);
  }
  public BadServerStateException(String internalServerError, String resourceId, Object p2, Throwable cause) {
    super(internalServerError + ": " + resourceId + " -> " + p2, cause);
  }
}
```

Then, given you have an application and a service like this, ...

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968;

import org.hibernate.JDBCException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.SQLException;

@Service
public class MyService {
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("My service");
  }

  public void doSomethingElse() {
    throw new JDBCException("uh-oh, database error", new SQLException("syntax error in SQL"));
  }

  public void doAnotherThing() {
    throw new ClassCastException("oops, cannot cast Foo to Bar");
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) {
    MyService myService = appContext.getBean(MyService.class);
    myService.doSomething();
    try {
      myService.doSomethingElse();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
      myService.doAnotherThing();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

..., just change the aspect to use the constructor with the `Throwable` parameter and pass on the original exception:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.hibernate.JDBCException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(0)
public class TcInternalExceptionAspect {
  private static final String INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = "Internal Server Error";
  private static final Object DATABASE_ERROR_CODE = 11;
  private static final Object INTERNAL_ERROR_CODE = 22;
  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcInternalExceptionAspect.class);

  @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
  public void applicationServicePointcut() {}

  @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "applicationServicePointcut()", throwing = "e")
  public void translate(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
    String resourceId = getResourceId();
    if (e instanceof JDBCException) {
      String message = e.getMessage() == null || e.getMessage().trim().equals("")
        ? e.getClass().toString()
        : e.getMessage();
      log.error(message);
      throw new BadServerStateException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, resourceId, DATABASE_ERROR_CODE, e);
    }
    else {
      String message = e.getMessage() == null || e.getMessage().trim().equals("")
        ? e.getClass().toString()
        : e.getMessage();
      log.error(message);
      throw new BadServerStateException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, resourceId, INTERNAL_ERROR_CODE, e);
    }
  }

  private String getResourceId() {
    return "ABC-123";
  }
}
```

Then, on the console you should see:

```
2022-12-10 08:51:26.017  INFO 23880 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q73557968.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 2.585 seconds (JVM running for 3.175)
My service
2022-12-10 08:51:26.031 ERROR 23880 --- [           main] d.s.s.q.TcInternalExceptionAspect        : uh-oh, database error
2022-12-10 08:51:26.033 ERROR 23880 --- [           main] d.s.s.q.TcInternalExceptionAspect        : oops, cannot cast Foo to Bar
de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.BadServerStateException: Internal Server Error: ABC-123 -> 11
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.TcInternalExceptionAspect.translate(TcInternalExceptionAspect.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:617)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22cb0578.doSomethingElse(<generated>)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.DemoApplication.doStuff(DemoApplication.java:24)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.JDBCException: uh-oh, database error
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.MyService.doSomethingElse(MyService.java:14)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.MyService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7d395b25.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: syntax error in SQL
    ... 16 more
de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.BadServerStateException: Internal Server Error: ABC-123 -> 22
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.TcInternalExceptionAspect.translate(TcInternalExceptionAspect.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:617)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22cb0578.doAnotherThing(<generated>)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.DemoApplication.doStuff(DemoApplication.java:30)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: oops, cannot cast Foo to Bar
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.MyService.doAnotherThing(MyService.java:17)
    at de.scrum_master.spring.q73557968.MyService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7d395b25.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)
    ... 9 more
```

See? Of course, you see the newly created exception and its current stack trace, but the causing exception's stack trace is also displayed. This is a standard means of exception handling in Java.

Comment: BadServerStateExsception in my application looks a little different, as I  added in the OP. It's used across the application. Not sure, how can I make this work.

Comment: You can make it work by overloading the exception's constructor similar to my version. IMO, every exception should optionally be able to accept a cause, because it is customary throughout the JDK and many Java applications. Sorry, but an aspect cannot fix bad application design for you. BTW, you are not showing the full exception, only constructors calling `this(..)`. I am fairly sure, at some point one constructor calls `super(..)`, i.e. you can easily extend that to also pass on a `Throwable cause`.

Comment: A bad workaround would be to not throw a `BadServerStateException` but a `RuntimeException`, adding the cause to the constructor call. Better go and refactor the exception to behave like an exception should. Your users and co-developers reading stack traces will thank you for that. The `BadServerStateException` is intentionally hiding the cause, so you cannot expect it to be logged. The problem sits in front of the computer.

Comment: Okay, but I did not find any way to pass the Throwable, as the superclass of BadServerStateException i.e. AbstractThrowableProblem does not have any constructor to accept Throwable.

Comment: I think, I don't have any other way other than the workaround you suggested in the comment.

Comment: It seems, by enabling a causal chain, there can be a way to achieve this, as mentioned here: https://www.baeldung.com/problem-spring-web. Let me see.

Comment: Are you using something like https://javadoc.io/static/org.zalando/problem/0.20.3/org/zalando/problem/AbstractThrowableProblem.html? I just googled it. Why does Zalando need to re-invent exception handling? Anyway, it seems you found a workaround. I am happy for you. P.S.: `AbstractThrowableProblem` does have two constructors accepting `ThrowableProblem cause` elements. Maybe this is what your exception should use to forward causes.

Comment: Sadly the above approach which I suggested did not work. In the approach you suggested above, I doubt if there exists a way to construct a ThrowableProblem from Throwable.

Comment: Well, you could add the stack trace to the `detail` constructor parameter, printing it to a byte buffer or so, even though that sounds ugly. But it would certainly be feasible. But really, you should use exceptions which simply accept a throwable.

Comment: As you suggested above, passing Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()) in detail parameter, hope, this will work.

Comment: One related question here, the aspect in OP is actually used in my application as well as other applications also. So I am thinking to replace the above aspect with another aspect in my application so that in case of any exception in my application only, the new aspect comes into play.  So is this possible to achieve the same?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Anyway, I think I answered your original question already, and we wrote way too many comments already. SO is not a discussion forum. Please ask a new question, but this time please provide a full reproducer project (MCVE), just like I did in my answer. It actually is your job to present one. Thanks.